# DNN : SSL enabled site but host menu not working

Tags: dotnetnuke

I have a dnn website which I have configured as secure. After making it secure whenever I access secure pages of host menu, it throws error and I am unable to access host secure pages.

Please help me ASAP!

Error Details :

Method: DotNetNuke.Entities.Portals.PortalSettings.GetPortalSettings
StackTrace:
Message: System.Exception: Unhandled Error: ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at DotNetNuke.Entities.Portals.PortalSettings.GetPortalSettings(Int32 TabId, PortalAliasInfo objPortalAliasInfo) at DotNetNuke.Entities.Portals.PortalSettings..ctor(Int32 tabId, PortalAliasInfo objPortalAliasInfo) at DotNetNuke.HttpModules.UrlRewriteModule.OnBeginRequest(Object s, EventArgs e) at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
Thanks,
Kusum

Comment: Have a look in the log to see more details about the error thrown and add the result of it to your question please

Comment: ahh what a joyfully useful error message, the wonders of DNN never cease to amaze! Please try and follow my answer below and let me know if it works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to re-install your certificate
2. Clear Web Browser Cache
3. Restart Site (add a white space to your web.config file and save)

Comment: HI Treemonkey, Thanks for your reply but it is not working after applying the steps told by you. Please let me know if any other solution, still giving the same error.